# Binding variables in the Controller's promises

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am new in JS and TypeScript and I am just want to check myself. He is my contoller:

```
class DefectListController implements IDefectListModel {
    itemId: string;
    defects: any[];

    static $inject = ['$stateParams', 'defectResource'];

    constructor($stateParams: any, defectResource: any) {
        this.itemId = $stateParams.itemid;

        // defects
        defectResource.defectsByItemId($stateParams.itemid).then(function (data) {
            this.defects = data;
        });
    }
}
```

In this case I have `itemId` variable in my view, but I don't have `defects` variable.  As I see the reason of this is that `this` is the `Window` in the promise.

So I have fix my code like this (and now it is working):

```
class DefectListController implements IDefectListModel {
    itemId: string;
    defects: any[];

    static $inject = ['$stateParams', 'defectResource'];

    constructor($stateParams: any, defectResource: any) {
        var self = this;
        this.itemId = $stateParams.itemid;

        // defects
        defectResource.defectsByItemId($stateParams.itemid).then(function (data) {
            self.defects = data;
        });
    }
}
```

I am just wondering is it a good solution?  Or may be there is a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know TypeScript but you should also be able to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). More here ~ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49872/using-var-self-this-or-bindthis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> am just wondering is it a good solution? Or may be there is a better way to do it?

This is a good solution. A better one would be to use an arrow function:

```
  // defects
    defectResource.defectsByItemId($stateParams.itemid).then((data) => {
        this.defects = data;
    });
```

More on arrow functions in TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html